# How to get date and time from Date object returned from GetUpdatedResult.getLatestDateCovered()

Tags: apex, integration, date, datetime

`Database.getUpdated()` returns a [`GetUpdatedResult`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_class_database_getupdatedresult.htm) object, which has a `getLatestDateCovered()` method.  This method returns a `Date` object.  When I do a System.debug to view the returned Date, I see a date and a time:

```
DEBUG|result of GetUpdatedResult.getLatestDateCovered(): 2016-09-09 04:39:00
```

However, since this is a `Date` and not a `Datetime`, I can't seem to access the time element of the object (there are obviously no `hour()` or `minute()` methods on the `Date` class, and when I try to convert the `Date` to a `String` using `format()`, it drops the time).  I would like to store the full `Datetime` value and use it as the 'startDate' parameter when I make my next call to `Database.getUpdated`.

I have a feeling I'm missing something obvious.  How can I create a `Datetime` object that includes the date AND time returned from GetUpdatedResult.getLatestDateCovered()?

Comment: did you tried `datetime.parse(datetimeString)` or `Datetime.valueOf(datetimeString)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately you can't. As it is stated in [Primitive Types doc](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/langCon_apex_primitives.htm):

> **Date**:     A value that indicates a particular day. Unlike Datetime values, Date values **contain no information about time**. Date values must always be created with a system static method.

`getLatestDateCovered()` returns `Date`, you can create a DateTime as follows:

```
Date dateInst = getUpdatedResult.getLatestDateCovered();
Datetime dt = datetime.newInstance(dateInst.year(), dateInst.month(), dateInst.day());
```

However, as you may guess, you can't keep time information since Date class doesn't provide a way to do it.

The fact that you can see time using `System.debug(dateInst)` is one of those weird things that only Apex-Compiler devs could explain. However, this quote from [Date class doc](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_date.htm#apex_methods_system_date) gives a hint that Date instances store (or they did at least) time info:

> In API version 33.0 or earlier, if you call Date.valueOf with an object that represents a Datetime, the method returns a Date value that contains the hours, minutes, and seconds. In version 34.0 and later, Date.valueOf converts the object to a valid Date without the time information. To convert a variable of type Datetime to a Date, use the Datetime.date method.

Even if `Date` contains time info, currently this class doesn't provide a way to access to that information.

In the case of `Database.getUpdated(objectName, startDate, endDate)`, startDate and endDate are handled as `DateTime` objects, which can include hours, minutes and seconds. If you actually need the time that you see in the debug logs, that's actually the time value of `endDate`, so you can just get that time from that argument.

```
DateTime startDate = DateTime.newInstanceGMT(2016, 9, 1, 1, 0, 0);
DateTime endDate = DateTime.newInstanceGMT(2016, 9, 2, 6, 0, 0);
Database.GetUpdatedResult r = Database.getUpdated('Opportunity', startDate, endDate);

system.debug(r.getLatestDateCovered()); 
// |DEBUG|2016-09-02 06:00:00

system.debug(endDate.formatGMT('yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss'));
// |DEBUG|2016-09-02 06:00:00
```

Comment: Thanks @Joca, this is very helpful.  I don't understand _why_ the `GetUpdatedResult` object would return a `Date` and not a `Datetime` from the `getLatestDateCovered()` method, but it is good to know that the `endDate` parameter passed in has the same `Datetime` value - so I can use that in my design.  Thanks again!

Comment: You're welcome, and yeah, I also think that there are some things in apex libraries that don't make too much sense.